# Converting a 2d char array to String

Tags: java

I am trying to convert this 2d char array to a String. The issue is it is outputting 100,000 characters even through the input array is no where near that. What is the correct way to convert a 2d char array to a string?

```
public String printMaze(char[][] maze) {
    String s= "";
    for(int i=0;i<maze.length;i++){
        for(int j=0; i<maze[i].length;j++){
            s= maze.toString();;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: provide sample input and output to make it more clear.

Comment: You are calling `maze.toString()`, how do you want to join the characters? Because you could do `return Arrays.deepToString(maze);`

Comment: It does not output any. The test server I used killed it once it hit 100k

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8995883/2308683

Comment: It is  supposed to return a String representation of the character array

Comment: You aren't getting the individual characters at all. `maze.toString()` is the entire array object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner loop has a problem and also I don't see you actually concetanting a string from the 2D character array.  Here is the problem with the inner loop:

```
for (int j=0; i < maze[i].length; j++) {
        //   ^^^^ this will always be true for certain values of i
        // it should be j < maze[i].length
    s= maze.toString();;
}
```

In other words, your inner loop might be spinning forever, depending on the bounds of the maze.  Instead, try the following code:

```
public String printMaze(char[][] maze) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i=0; i < maze.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < maze[i].length; j++) {
            s += maze[i][j];
        }
        // uncomment next line if you want the maze to have rows
        // s += "\n";
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

But as @ElliottFrisch mentioned, you could just return `Arrays.deepToString(maze)`.

Comment: I'm assuming a maze should have rows, not one long string

Comment: why on earth can you not use `StringBuilder` ? It is a java.lang class

Comment: thank you. we can not use string builder because we have not gone over it yet

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help..

```
public String printMaze(char[][] maze) {
 String s= "";
 for(int i=0;i < maze.length;i++){
    for(int j=0; j < maze[i].length;j++){
        s = s + maze[i][j];
    }
 }
 return s;
}
```

Comment: giving me a array out of bound exception

Comment: please also explain what you have changed

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the length of your 2D array where you are getting exception. And if you have already modified your code then please ignore

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I haven't noticed when I was typing.